# JavaScript random margin for div only working on first div only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm displaying images from all users. And I want them to appear in different places. I have this code right now:

```html
@foreach($users as $user)
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center" id="fighter">
    <img src="{{$user->char_image}}">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

```js
var fighter = document.getElementById('fighter');
fighter.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "px;");
```

The problem is that the margin changes for first div only.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You're targeting an id - you can only have an id on the page once. You should use `class="fighter"` instead and target the classes in your JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` attributes *have* to be unique in the DOM. The issue you're seeing is because of this expectation. To work with multiple grouped elements, use a `class` instead:

```html
@foreach($users as $user)
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center fighter">
    <img src="{{$user->char_image}}">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Then in JS you need to loop over those elements and set the `margin-top` individually:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('fighter')).forEach(function(el) {
  el.style.marginTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "px";
});
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('.fighter').css('margin-top', function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + "px";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you are using ID to reference the timer containers. When you use `getElementById`, you will always get the first element having the respective ID.

You may use something like `getElementsByClassName()`, that will return you all incidences of the specific class.

**Try this approach:**

HTML rendering:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <div class="col-md-2 text-center fighter">
    <img src="{{$user->char_image}}">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

JavaScript:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fighter');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  element.setAttribute("style", "margin-top:" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100) + "px;")
})
```

PS: You should look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com). It can let your life much more easier, having such more clean implementations.

If you have any problems with it, let me now :)